# Fitting a sigmoid curve using a logistic function in R

Tags: r, nls, sigmoid

I have data that follows a sigmoid curve and I would like fit a logistic function to extract the three (or two) parameters for each participant. I have found some methods online, but I'm not sure which is the correct option.

[This tutorial](https://kyrcha.info/2012/07/08/tutorials-fitting-a-sigmoid-function-in-r) explains that you should use the nls() function like this:

```
fitmodel <- nls(y~a/(1 + exp(-b * (x-c))), start=list(a=1,b=.5,c=25))
 ## get the coefficients using the coef function 
params=coef(fitmodel)
```

... where you clearly need the starting values to find the best-fitting values (?).

And then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033176/using-r-to-fit-a-sigmoidal-curve) explains that to get the starting values, you can use a "selfstarting model can estimate good starting values for you, so you don't have to specify them":

```
fit <- nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, xmid, scal), data = data.frame(x, y))
```

However somewhere else I also read that you should use the SSlogis function for fitting a logistic function. Please could someone confirm whether these two steps are the best way to go about it? Or should I use values that I have extracted from previous similar data for the starting values?

Additionally, what should I do if I don't want the logistic function to be defined by the asymptote at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a best way but `SSlogis` does eliminate having to set starting values whereas if you specify the formula you have more control over the parameterization.

If the question is really how to fix `a` at a predetermined level, here the value 1, without rewriting the formula then set `a` before running `nls` and omit it from the starting values.

```
a <- 1
fo <- y ~ a / (1 + exp(-b * (x-c)))
nls(fo, start = list(b = 0.5, c = 25))
```

Alternately this substitutes a=1 into formula `fo` giving `fo2` without having to rewrite the formula yourself.

```
fo2 <- do.call("substitute", list(fo, list(a = 1)))
nls(fo2, start = list(b = 0.5, c = 25))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! My question was aimed at whether it makes sense statistically to do both, i.e. take the whole dataset and use the SSlogis function, then take the three values it gives me (or two if I'm using 1 for a) and put them in the self-specified nls function to get the more "exact" parameter values?
Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a statistical issue. It is a numerical issue. As long as the starting values are sufficiently close to the answer and the usual requirements are met it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As @G. Grothendieck writes, there is no general "best way", it always depends on you particular aims. Use of `SSLogis` is a good idea, as you don't need to specify start values, but a definition of an own function is more flexible. See the following example, where we use heuristics to derive start values ourselves instead of specifying them manually. Then we fit a logistic model and as a small bonus, the Baranyi growth model with an explicit lag phase.

```
# time (t)
x <- c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)

# Algae cell counts (Mio cells per ml)
y <- c(0.88, 1.02, 1.43, 2.79, 4.61, 7.12,
       6.47, 8.16, 7.28, 5.67, 6.91)

## we now plot the data linearly and logarithmically
## the layout function is another way to subdivide the plotting area
nf <- layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE), respect = TRUE)
layout.show(nf) # this shows how the plotting area is subdivided

plot(x, y)
plot(x, log(y))

## we see that the first points show the steepest increase,
## so we can estimate a start value of the growth rate
r <- (log(y[5]) - log(y[1])) / (x[5] - x[1])
abline(a=log(y[1]), b=r)

## this way, we have a heuristics for all start parameters:
## r:  steepest increase of y in log scale
## K:  maximum value
## N0: first value

## we can check this by plotting the function with the start values
f <- function(x, r, K, N0) {K /(1 + (K/N0 - 1) * exp(-r *x))}
plot(x, y, pch=16, xlab="time (days)", ylab="algae (Mio cells)")
lines(x, f(x, r=r, K=max(y), N0=y[1]), col="blue")

pstart <- c(r=r, K=max(y), N0=y[1])
aFit   <- nls(y ~ f(x, r, K,N0), start = pstart, trace=TRUE)

x1 <- seq(0, 25, length = 100)
lines(x1, predict(aFit, data.frame(x = x1)), col = "red")
legend("topleft",
       legend = c("data", "start parameters", "fitted parameters"),
       col = c("black", "blue", "red"),
       lty = c(0, 1, 1),
       pch = c(16, NA, NA))

summary(aFit)
(Rsquared <- 1 - var(residuals(aFit))/var(y))

## =============================================================================
## Approach with Baranyi-Roberts model
## =============================================================================

## sometimes, a logistic is not good enough. In this case, use another growth
## model
baranyi <- function(x, r, K, N0, h0) {
  A <- x + 1/r * log(exp(-r * x) + exp(-h0) - exp(-r * x - h0))
  y <- exp(log(N0) + r * A - log(1 + (exp(r * A) - 1)/exp(log(K) - log(N0))))
  y
}

pstart <- c(r=0.5, K=7, N0=1, h0=2)
fit2   <- nls(y ~ baranyi(x, r, K, N0, h0), start = pstart, trace=TRUE)

lines(x1, predict(fit2, data.frame(x = x1)), col = "forestgreen", lwd=2)

legend("topleft",
       legend = c("data", "logistic model", "Baranyi-Roberts model"),
       col = c("black", "red", "forestgreen"),
       lty = c(0, 1, 1),
       pch = c(16, NA, NA))
```

[image: Sigmoidal curve]

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer! What I don't understand is, should I use both SSlogis and my own logistic function? I.e., what is the difference between:

a) use SSlogis to get starting values and THEN use nls as I've written it above with those starting values
AND
b) using only SSlogis and then reporting the values it gives me as the best-fitting parameters.

Thank you!

Comment: In programming, the question is often not "should I ...", but the question is what is better for a given purpose. Please decide yourself: Use `SSlogis` if this does what you want, and use an own function if you want to have more flexibility. For testing purposes, it is also a good idea to compare both.